# What is the use of the plus sign here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, syntax

I have a simple javascript syntax question.
I have this link below and it has a code snippet which uses d3.js to render a bar graph.

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/HQz1BL9SECFIsQ5bG8qb?p=preview
```

And the thing I don't understand is..

from script.js file, there is a statement,

```
 data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.value = +d.value;
});
```

and if you just remove the plus sign prepended d.value like this,

```
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.value = d.value;
});
```

as you can see, the tick values on y-axis changes.. but as far as I know, prepending + before a value means is to convert any value to a number type.

and if you look at the data from bar-data.csv file, all values there are numbers, so I think nothing really should change whether remove that + or not...  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"...and if you look at the data from bar-data.csv file, all values there are numbers"*... No, actually they are not numbers after the file is loaded/parsed: they are **strings**.

What happens is that `d3.csv`, which uses `dsv.parse`, loads all the fields as strings. You can see this in the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv_parse):

> If a row conversion function is not specified, field values are **strings**. For safety, there is no automatic conversion to numbers, dates, or other types. (emphasis mine)

We can easily show this. Suppose we have this CSV, with numbers as values:

```
foo,bar
17,34
42,12
```

As the Stack snippet doesn't allow us to save a CSV file, I'll use `d3.csvParse` here instead of `d3.csv`, but the result is the same. Have a look at the console:

```js
var csv = `foo,bar
17,34
42,12`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv);

data.forEach(function(d) {
  for (key in d) {
    console.log(d[key] + ": " + typeof d[key])
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Now let's use the unary plus to convert only the values in the `foo` column:

```js
var csv = `foo,bar
17,34
42,12`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, row);

data.forEach(function(d) {
  for (key in d) {
    console.log(d[key] + ": " + typeof d[key])
  }
})

function row(d) {
  d.foo = +d.foo;
  return d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

---

PS: Just to explain the behaviour in your plunker if you remove the unary plus: the higher number in the CSV is 478, which is used for the axis' domain. However, removing the unary plus, the higher value becomes "53", which as a string is higher than "478":

```js
console.log("53" > "478")
```

Comment: 1. Unless data type is specified explicitly, all loaded data from csv file are strings as default for some kind of safety.
2. The reason for the behaviour from the example, is that "53" has larger value than "478".
Thank you for awesome answer ! 
but there is one more thing.. when I take the unary + off and modified the value of first row in bar-data.csv, 2013-01,53  ---->    2013-01, 53 (I gave one space before 53), the graph behaves normally. wondering what that one space does ?

Comment: @JayJeong An empty space is a lower value: `console.log(" " > "1")` returns `false`. Now, change the value of any of the rows to `9` to see what happens...

Comment: @JayJeong No worries. When I first read your question I thought that it would be definitely a duplicate... however, despite several Q/A regarding problems related to the unary plus in row functions, I was surprised because after some searches I couldn't find any question specifically asking what you asked here.